# How to put data from MySQL table to Google Chart API?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-visualization

I'm struggling to work out how to make a chart out of the data I have, heres an example.

My Chart with dummy data should look like this:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Margarita Murphy', 'Lora Gonzales', 'Mario Moran', 'Wefico Local Faire', 'Zegko Collection', 'Saxux Program for Youth', 'Test New location venue'],
    ['4/12', 9, 74, 10, 8, 93, 33, 90], 
    ['5/12', 10, 168, 0, 10, 198, 108, 154], 
    ['6/12', 9, 174, 12, 12, 165, 96, 261], 
    ['7/12', 12, 288, 8, 36, 180, 264, 140], 
    ['8/12', 40, 275, 15, 30, 275, 395, 170], 
    ['9/12', 54, 534, 30, 48, 240, 246, 552], 
    ['10/12', 28, 518, 63, 28, 182, 672, 98], 
    ['11/12', 56, 520, 8, 64, 424, 568, 704], 
    ['12/12', 45, 675, 9, 63, 864, 567, 756], 
    ['1/13', 90, 570, 40, 70, 350, 510, 150], 
    ['2/13', 55, 946, 110, 55, 253, 429, 88], 
    ['3/13', 96, 684, 12, 96, 528, 1140, 468], 
    ['4/13', 52, 832, 104, 130, 1261, 1235, 663], 
    ['5/13', 28, 756, 70, 70, 1050, 910, 728], 
    ['6/13', 105, 930, 15, 60, 1440, 660, 690], 
    ['7/13', 144, 1600, 96, 64, 1312, 1488, 1120], 
]);
```

So as you can see it has a list of items, with how many views it has had per month going back in time.

The problem I am having is when I get the data from MySQL I want to loop though the views, which would be going vertically down in the column, instead of accross. How would I go about making it go horizontal like so:

```
['4/12', item1.views, item2.view]
['5/12', item1.views, item2.view]
```

I'm getting really confused by this...

**Example Data**

```
-------------------
|date|views|ref_id|
|----|-----|------|
|4/12|123  |2     |
|5/12|526  |7     |
|6/12|2    |1     |
|7/12|46   |3     |
-------------------
```

**EDIT:**

Playing around with setting the dates as variables first and then looping though everything and adding the data to the correct one?

```
$month4_12 = "['4/12', ";
$month5_12 = "['5/12', ";

foreach($views_data as $data){
    ${"month_$data->date"} .= $data->views . ', ';
}

$month4_12 .= "],";
$month5_12 .= "],";
```

**EDIT2:**

So here's what I have now, it has a few problems though, if the views table doesn't contain a record, it doesn't count as it only goes off what it finds in the database... It no obviously doesn't work as it doesn't have the correct amount of columns compared to titles.

```
// Get views for chart
$views_data = $this->content_model->get_chart_view_data();

// First make the months
$month = 1;
while($month <= 16){
    $month_text = date('d/m/y');
    $month_text = strtotime($month_text . ' -'.$month.' months');
    $month_text_display = date('n/y', $month_text);
    $month_text_variable = str_replace('/', '_', $month_text_display);
    ${"month_$month_text_variable"} = "['".$month_text_display."', ";

    // Now add the data
    foreach($views_data as $row){
        ${"month_$month_text_variable"} .= $row->views . ', ';
    }
    ${"month_$month_text_variable"} = rtrim(${"month_$month_text_variable"}, ", ");

    // Finish the lines
    ${"month_$month_text_variable"} .= "],\n";

    $month++;
}

// Now join the lot!
$month = 1;
$chart_data = '';
while($month <= 16){
    $month_text = date('d/m/y');
    $month_text = strtotime($month_text . ' -'.$month.' months');
    $month_text_display = date('n/y', $month_text);
    $month_text_variable = str_replace('/', '_', $month_text_display);
    $chart_data .= ${"month_$month_text_variable"};
    $month++;
}

$data['chart_data'] = rtrim($chart_data, ",\n");

echo $data['chart_data'];
```

This gives the output:

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', 'Margarita Murphy', 'Lora Gonzales', 'Mario Moran', 'Wefico Local Faire', 'Zegko Collection', 'Saxux Program for Youth', 'Test New location venue'],
        ['7/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['6/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['5/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['4/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['3/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['2/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['1/13', 2, 1, 1],
        ['12/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['11/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['10/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['9/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['8/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['7/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['6/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['5/12', 2, 1, 1],
        ['4/12', 2, 1, 1]
]);
```

**EDIT 3**

Heres how the views data is stored in the database, you can see that a day with no views simply has no record

[image]

Comment: can you add an example of how your 'vertical' data looks, to give us an idea please

Comment: ok, I don't know about anyone else, can you give me a piece of input and how you want it to look afterwards please, sorry I'm slow today

Comment: I've added the code I have so far and it's output if it helps

Comment: so I'm guessing the `2, 1, 1]` is only correct for `7/13` and it should be different for the others?

Comment: Yeah, theres only 1 days worth of data in the database so everything else should be 0

Comment: Added a screenshot of the data stored in the database

Comment: This is the wrong approach to the problem; it won't get you the results you want.  Are the "ref_id" values referring to the column names in your table ('Margarita Murphy', 'Lora Gonzales', etc)?

Comment: Yeah they refer to the the names

Comment: You need to pivot the data in your SQL query; see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pivot the data in your SQL query.  Since MySQL doesn't support pivots natively, you have to cheat a bit.  Each pivoted column in your final output will be in this form:

```
IF(ref_id = <this column's reference id>, views, 0) AS <column name>
```

and then you group by the date column, like this:

```
SELECT
    data,
    IF(ref_id = 327, views, 0) AS column_327,
    IF(ref_id = 329, views, 0) AS column_329,
    // etc...
FROM <table name>
WHERE <conditions>
GROUP BY date
```

Then you can iterate over the output to build a DataTable object.

If you don't know all of the ref_id values ahead of time (or there are a lot of them), then you can query to get a list of ref_id's and build the query programmatically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref_id FROM <table name>
```